# How can I fix google sheetf if(len) formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

DOes anyone know why am I getting an error in the following formula and how can I fix it?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(L2:L),L2:L&"03/2022",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Try to replace `, ` with `;`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(L2:L); L2:L&"03/2022"; ))
```